# Question regarding logarithms

Tags: logarithms

Can you factor out the $m$ out of $\ln(c\cdot x^m)$  where $c$ is a constant?

Comment: **HINT**: Use this rule first: $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$

Comment: If you mean $\ln(cx^m)$, with $c>0$ and $x>0$, then you can write it as $\ln c+m\ln x$.

Answer (score 1):

- We use the fact that $\ln(ab) = \ln a + \ln b$,
- and the fact that $\ln(a^b) = b\ln a$

$$\ln(cx^m) = \ln(c) + \ln(x^m) = \ln(c) + m\ln(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

If we have $y=ln(c.x^m)$, then $y=ln(c)+mln(x)$, so $\dfrac{y-ln(c)}{m}=ln(x)$ and so:

$$x=e^{\dfrac{y-ln(c)}{m}}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $m\not = 0$, then we have
$$ \ln\left(cx^m\right) = \ln c + \ln x^m = \ln c + m\ln x = m\left(\frac1m\ln c + \ln x\right)$$